# Directshow multiple renderers on one stream

Tags: directshow

I have directshow player in a c++ builder VCL application.  It runs fine but I have it as part of a multiple form application and want to display  the video onto the second monitor.  This is so I can have extra buttons plus the video on monitor 1 and just the video on monitor 2.

As directshow doesn't give an event when it updates the display, is there any way I can determine when a new video image is being displayed and copy this to the second display?

Alternatively,  is it possible to have two video renderers onto the one source, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do this.  I added an "Infinite Tee" filter and then added two renderers to the Tee.  This then allowed separate windows for each renderer coming off the single stream.

```cpp
    // Add an infinite TEE
    hr = AddFilterByCLSID(m_pGraph, CLSID_InfTee, &m_pTee, L"InfTee");
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    teeInput  = FindPin(m_pTee, PINDIR_INPUT, 0);
    vidOutput = FindPin(pSource, PINDIR_OUTPUT, 0);
    m_pGraph->Connect(vidOutput, teeInput);
```